# Xamarin build agent not running on mac error

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a cross platform xamarin project running on Windows VS 2017. I have a mac which I am connected to with the latest version of Xcode and VS installed with the xamarin versions matching. When I go to build the project, I get an error: "*The Xamarin Build Agent is not running on the Mac. An active Build Agent is required to perform the build*".

I know for sure that I'm connected, and that the xamarin versions are the same on the mac and windows. I followed all the steps here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/

I'm at a loss here, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a courtesy check, you do have xamarin studio and the correct sdk's installed on the mac right? In addition, I think that you should be running the mac with the latest OS (Sierra) for best results. Sometimes the mac agent can be a bit temperamental.

Comment: I have visual studio with latest version of xamarin installed on mac. I don't think it's possible to download xamarin studio anymore. It's been deprecated in favor of using VS. And the OS is Sierra.

Comment: Strange, I have xamarin studio installed on a mac VM and I can't use my mac as a build agent without that installed. The visual studio on the non-mac side seems to communicate with the local mac's xamarin studio to build and run.

Comment: Hmm do you know where it's possible to get that download?

Comment: [the xamarin mac agent guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/) says you need "Xamarin Studio 5.10 or higher", yet on the [download page](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.3/), it conflictingly says that "Visual Studio for Mac is replacing Xamarin Studio".

Comment: Found it! Click the "Download Xamarin - for mac" after logging in to your xamarin account on [this page](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads). Should be the primary button if you visit the site on a mac.

Comment: @BennettYeo Xamarin Studio is deprecated and does not have anything to do with the remote build process. Visual Studio (Windows) will deploy the Build Agent to the Mac over `ssh`.

Comment: @SushiHangover, are you able to build without having xamarin studio installed? When I was in the process of setting up my build mac I found that I was unable to build to the mac until it was installed. Moreover, Xamarin studio is still currently listed as a requirement in the [official guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/). I am using an older version of xamarin so that might make a difference to me.

Comment: @Programninja Double check that you have matching versions between your Mac and Windows, seems a lot of people have auto-updates set on Windows and are getting a newer version (there is also a bugzilla or two about that) but are not updating their Mac....

Comment: @BennettYeo You have to install `Mono` and `Xamarin.iOS` on Mac build host, but not Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio for Mac. Once you setup remote login on the Mac, of course you have to keep the versions in sync between the machines ;-) otherwise the error in this question will be seen. As far as versions go, unless you are running the "old" Xamarin 3.x with Visual Studio 2010/13, Visual Studio (Windows) will take care of installing build agent...

Comment: @SushiHangover, Touché, I pretty much only use xamarin studio on the mac side to keep mono and xamarin.iOS up to date.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the input guys. I am 99% certain that the versions are the same. Is it possible to just run the project from the mac? Like the android builds to a simulator on the windows machine and the iOS version builds to a simulator on the mac?

Comment: @Programninja `run the project from the mac?` Sure, sync the solution over to the Mac (via git, etc..)  and open the `.sln` in Visual Studio for Mac....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, i found this solution on xamarin forum 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100185/the-xamarin-build-agent-is-not-running-on-the-mac

I hope this of help

Comment: Thank you! One of the solutions in that link solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the error :
"The Xamarin Build Agent is not running on the Mac. An active Build Agent is required to perform the build".
Tools -> extension and updates
Find Xamarin.Apple SDK
Click Revert.

Everythings come back to normal.
Thanks for solution

Benoist